# Cant seem to return a null pointer in my strstr function

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

I'm having trouble with my `strstr` function. My function works but I'm not passing my professor's tests. I keep getting segmentation faults.

Basically, it's not returning a null pointer whenever the sub-string (needle) is not in the haystack, and vice versa.

```cpp
const char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle) { 
    // TODO
    const char *a = haystack;
    const char *b = needle;
    while(true){
        if(!*b){
            return haystack;
        }
        if(!*a){
            return nullptr;
        }
        if(*a++ != *b++){
            a = ++haystack;
            b = needle;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered `if ... else if (..) ... else`? and what if `haystack` or `needle` is `nullptr` to begin with or empty-string?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin no I have not. Do you think that might resolve my problem?

Comment: You may want to add another pointer to mark the location in `haystack` where you match the first character in `needle` (say `const char *sp = haystack;`). I would do something like `while (true) { if (*a && *a == *b)  { if (b == needle) sp = a; a++, b++ } else if (!*b) return sp; else if (!*a) break; else { a = ++sp; b = needle; }} return nullptr;`

Comment: But honestly, what you have works quite well if you just add a preliminary check to catch `NULL` and empty parameters, e.g. add up top `if (!a || !b || !*a || !*b) return nullptr;` and that pretty much covers it. Then you can enter your `while (true)` loop knowing your parameters are valid pointers and neither point to the empty-string ( 1st character is nul-terminating character)